# how can i substitute this symbol' for = with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to substitute '. with =

but this code  doens't work!
can any one help?

```
Cells.Replace What:="'.gcmd", Replacement:="=gcmd", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Is the `'` at the very start of the string?

Answer (score 1):

If the apostrophe is at the very start of the string, it is a Prefix Character and part of the formatting property of the string, not the value property. It tells excel to treat the value as text.

That being the case, you need to clear the format in addition to replacing the value.

Also note that if you do not have a named formula or range defined on your worksheet, the code will not work returning an application error (unless you define the format as Text).

Code could be something like below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub due()
 Dim R As Range, C As Range
 Dim FirstAddress As String

Set R = Range("A1:Z100") 'or whatever

With R
    Set C = Cells.Find(What:=".gcmd", Lookat:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = C.Address
        If C.PrefixCharacter = "'" Then
            C.ClearFormats
            C.NumberFormat = "@" 'omit if `gcmd` is a valid name
        End If
        C.Value = "=" & Mid(C, 2)

        Do
            Set C = .FindNext(C)
                If C Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                If C.Address = FirstAddress Then Exit Do

            'Note that you don't really have to test for the apostrophe.
            'You could just ClearFormats whether it is present or not.       
            If C.PrefixCharacter = "'" Then
                C.ClearFormats
                C.NumberFormat = "@" 'omit if `gcmd` is a valid name
            End If
            C.Value = "=" & Mid(C, 2)
        Loop
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: it almost works! that code removes the apostrophe but also removes everything that is in front of the "gcmd", this is a custom formula that can have several things, example: =gcmd(F5500A;"OUT "&A1), or =gcmd(F8508A;"X?";A2) etc...

Comment: @BrunoRanhel That's just a matter of change the two `C.Value=` lines to meet your requirements.  See my Edit.

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps try this?
(not actually really tested this, just rattled it off as an idea)

```
Private Sub SOAnswer()
Dim C As Range
Dim Str As String

For Each C In Range("A1: R35") 'Define your range here, or use Sheets(1).UsedRange for all cells on the sheet
    If InStr(1, ".gcmd", C.Value) <> 0 Then
        Str = C.Value
        C.Clear
        C.Formula = Replace(Str, ".gcmd", "=gcmd")
    End If
Next

End Sub
```